# Node Jquery Scraping Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, request, cheerio

I am trying to run a simple scrape on my webpage, but the issue I am running into is that I can't seem to bee selecting the HTML elements with my scraper correctly. I thought that I was grabbing the attributes correctly from my `<li>`, but I'm getting an `undefined` value for each of my object properties.

I'm looking to grab the `data-name`, `data-address` and `data-url` values.

scrape.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://personalSite.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('li').each(function(i, element){

        var li = $(this).contents();


        var name = li.attr('name');
        var address = li.attr('address');
        var url = li.attr('url');


        var metadata = {
            name : name,
            address : address,
            url : url
        };
        console.log(metadata);
    });
  }
});
```

html:

```
<li id="v1065" data-name="Jerry's Food" data-address="5120 West 43rd Street"  data-url="http://www.testsite1.com/" data-category="1"><a href="#" class="list-digital">
                                    <span class="venue-name">Jerry's Food</span><br />
                                    <span class="venue-address">5120 West 43rd Street</span>

                                    </a>
                                </li>                           
                                <li id="v249" data-name="Accel Partners" data-address="13482 Seventh Avenue" data-url="http://www.testsite2.com" data-category="3"><a href="#" class="list-digital">
                                    <span class="venue-name">Mike's Pizza</span><br />
                                    <span class="venue-address">13482 Seventh Avenue</span>                             
                                    </a>
                                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.attr()` method you should use full attribute names

```
var name = li.attr('data-name');
var address = li.attr('data-address');
var url = li.attr('data-url');
```

Or you may use

```
var name = li.data('name');
var address = li.data('address');
var url = li.data('url');
```

Comment: Hey @zavg, thank you for the answer, but after trying both of your suggestions I'm still getting undefined as the values for my object properties. Any thoughts as to why that might be? Am I not grabbing the right data?